# How to figure out what's wrong with a closed question?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just cast a reopen vote for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875925/net-c-sharp-how-can-i-use-a-native-data-structure-to-act-like-a-stack) and it didn't pass:

[image: STOP! Look and Listen.].

I stopped, looked, and listened, but it didn't help:

1. The text here doesn't say my *vote* didn't pass. It says *I* didn't pass.  Thank you for calling me stupid.
2. Even with 'the guidance above', and the text of the question helpfully on display, I have no idea what these so-called *serious problems* with the question are supposed to be.  How do I find out? The five people who voted for closing it don't explain. All they say is the question is too vague; well, I disagree.  Without any more specific clues as to what they think is wrong, I can't possibly edit to improve it.  I can't click *I understand*, either, because I don't.  All I can do is give up and accept the message that I'm too stupid to be reviewing on Stack Overflow.  Thanks again.

In short: there is a serious problem with this interface.  If you want reviewers, try not to piss them off.  I've always liked the review audit questions I've been given on answers, but this here is hard to stomach.

Comment: I don't understand how you interpolated _"didn't pass"_ as _"calling me stupid"_

Comment: I guess OP thinks not passing a review is linked to intelligence. @reinierpost fancy explaining what the correlation is?

Comment: Being one of the close voters I fully support the answer of @Makoto and have nothing more to add top the guidance given there.

Comment: *Without any more specific clues as to what they think is wrong, I can't possibly edit to improve it.* Even if you had clues you couldn't improve it because only the OP can make their question more specific. (I think that's true of most or all close reasons, actually.)

Comment: If you take math test and you fail how would you say it? There was a test and you didn't pass the test.

Comment: Hard to stomach for one review? Wow... You have a short fuse dude. Honestly when you fail a review approach it from a "hmmmm what did I miss?" not a "OMG STACK IS EVIL AND CALLING ME DUMB"... There are audits to make sure people pay attention to reviews... If you reviewed that question and thought it should be on the case, you may need to revisit the quality standards of this site :/

Comment: Clearly X/Y problem And duplicate. And need some edit. And need a link to MSDN List.add(). So Op should clarify then prove it's not a dupe of the hunderd 'Resize Array', 'Add Item to array'. And only after all those step, it can be a re open base on op habitily to make it less php quality post.

Comment: I find it ironic that this question is extremely downvoted :)

Comment: Despite the downvotes, I'm leaving this question up because I'm still as puzzled about this as I was when it happened. Makoto's rules are great, and I've seen them mentioned elsewhere, but  I can't find them covered in the Help Center, and I still don't think the question at hand violates them badly enough to be rejected.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Mercifully, the question has been deleted, but let's parse what's going on here.

First and foremost:  **the audit did its job.**  You were supposed to critically read this post to see if it was good enough to remain on the site, and you didn't do it.  There's really no other way to put that.

Now, onto the body of the question (reproduced here for < 10K):

> I don't have a key for my value, I neither don't want to build my own Stack class. I just need to push elements in an "array like" native structure. Like the "array_push" php function. All posts I've seen til now are just about creating classes to act like an Abstract Data Type, which is not want I need.
>
> Thanks to all possible answers.

Let's walk through this.

- They describe their desire to solve a problem; they just want to push elements into an array like structure.
- They **don't** describe any of the following:

  - What they've attempted
  - What code they've written that hasn't worked out for them
  - [**What their actual problem was**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248)
  - What would be a "correct" answer; that is, there's no real acceptance criteria here to describe what would satisfy

So, effectively, this question should have *remained* closed.  There's nothing here of value that anyone's going to get out of leaving this open.

Comment: Thank you for the four criteria, that's what I was looking for. By the way, how I'd apply them in this case: 1) You're right they should have added what they've attempted. 2) Code written is irrelevant here. 3) The actual problem is very clear: they want a standard data structure they can use as a stack and don't know how to find one. 4) It's very clear what a correct answer would be: point one out or explain there isn't any.